# Linkng of application with business.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

If we add an existing application (24 February 2014), for authorization in our web project in business.facebook.com, will id users registered on our website via the application remain the same or new id (id that returned for us)? Currently returning global user id. If the new id will return users can somehow compare  global id with a new id, whatever registered users could continue without problems enter the site under your account?
Thanks.

Comment: For users that first connected to an app before API v2.0 was introduced, the id that your app sees will continue to be the global id. App-scoped user ids are only issued for users that connect to an app for the first time after 2.0 was introduced.